# Angular 5 Firebase 2 -- Property 'includes' is missing in type

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular5

I am following a tutorial which is clearly outdated. But I tried my best to follow up with the migration guide but I am still stuck with this one little error.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireList, AngularFireObject, AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { ExpenseModel } from './expense-model';

@Injectable()
export class ExplistService {

  private basePath = '/UD';

  explist: AngularFireList<ExpenseModel[]> = null; //  list of objects
  exp: AngularFireObject<ExpenseModel> = null;

  createExpenseModel(exp: ExpenseModel): void  {
    this.explist.push(exp)
      .catch(error => this.handleError(error));
  }
```

I am getting the error at the line

```
this.explist.push(exp)
```

> Argument of type 'ExpenseModel' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'ExpenseModel[]'.   Property 'includes' is missing in type
>   'ExpenseModel'.

Comment: I think you meant to set the type of `explist` to `AngularFireList<ExpenseModel>` and not `AngularFireList<ExpenseModel[]>`.

Comment: No, I am not. Its exactly as its shown above.